# how to get video stream only through 'ReplayKit' iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, replaykit, webrtc-ios

I am using `ReplayKit` for getting a video stream. callback is continuously calling but `rpSampleType` returns something else. I want the video buffer only.

**Here is my code**

```
RPScreenRecorder.shared().startCapture(handler: { (cmSampleBuffer, rpSampleType, error) in
    if CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(cmSampleBuffer){

        switch rpSampleType {

        case RPSampleBufferType.video:
            // create the CVPixelBuffer
            let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(cmSampleBuffer)!
            let rtcpixelBuffer = RTCCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        default:
            print("sample has no matching type")
        }
    }
}) { (error) in
    print(error?.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Maybe provide a completion handler to `startCapture()`, it has an optional error as argument, you might get some useful debug info from it.

Comment: While debug cmSampleBuffer returns phoneApp. only single time it returns video type

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?